# Is it possible to call the TouchesBegan, touchesMoved and touchesEnded in SubView, and not in parentView?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uipopovercontroller

My problem is that the touchesBegan, touchesMoved and touchesEnded is taking the focus of :

```
- (void)didSelectWithTableView:(UITableView *)tableView controller:(UIViewController *)controller
{
...
}
```

in a tableview click. So didSelectWithTableView is never called...

Is it possible to have a subView (in popover) that is handled by touchesBegan, touchesMoved and touchesEnded, but not the parent View ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just call the super implementation of the methods. Along with your override code.

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    [super touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event];
    ...
}

- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    [super touchesMoved:touches withEvent:event];
    ...
}

- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    [super touchesEnded:touches withEvent:event];
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thx dude, that's the point. Now my next problem, if you can help me is in that ticket... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36135820/is-it-possible-to-draw-in-a-popover-appearing-by-clicking-in-a-tableviewcell   I try to have this three methods (touchebegan, moved and ended) in the subView that is a popover...